# Why is the console logger not synchronized with print?

Tags: python, asynchronous, logging, console

I just stumbled on the following surprising behavior when trying to show messages on the console using both `print` and a console logger:

```
import logging

for i in range(1, 10):
    print("Hello")
logging.warning("Hello world")

# Possible result:
Hello
WARNING:root:Hello world
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello

# Expected result:
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
WARNING:root:Hello world
```

How is this possible ?

Shouldn't it be guaranteed that the logger writes on its output stream (be it a file or a console) before returning?

Comment: Logging include `thread` and work out side mainloop.
Start two thread (mainloop + logging) for possible output.

Comment: Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: I'm looking for this behavior too. So I added a kludge to have each call to  `print()` flush `stdout`, which seems to make things better. But there are still many times when log output is displayed after `print()` output that was performed after the log call. I can't believe there's not a relatively way way to configure the logger in Python to synchronize with `print()`.

Answer (score 1):

These are a couple of different issues raised by your question. Firstly, the statement

```
logging.Formatter('{asctime} {name} {levelname:8s} {message}', style='{')
```

has no effect, because you are instantiating a `Formatter` and then throwing away the result. You need to assign the formatter to a `Handler`, which is added to a `Logger`. This is all documented in the [Python stdlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Secondly, there are two *different* output streams in your example - `print` writes to `sys.stdout` whereas `logging.warning`, with no other configuration, writes to `sys.stderr`. How these streams multiplex onto a single console is not well-defined and depends on how I/O buffering is set up, your operating system and other factors.

Comment: Sorry for the formatter, I forgot to remove it from my code.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72628419/19399090 , setting the log stream to sys.stdout in your basicConfing() call:

`logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, format=fmt, level=logging.INFO)`

As explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56559936/19399090 , by default the logger logs data to sys.stderr, while print prints data to sys.stdout. But sys.stderr and sys.stdout are not synchronized. Using sys.stdout for the logs too is a way to fix this.