# How to synchronize logging with printing in Python?

Tags: python, logging, printing

The following code

```
 logging.info('Collecting available features for location ' + source_feature['properties']['key'] + ' and date range [' + start_date + '..' + end_date + ']...')

    feature_start_time = datetime.now()

    target_directory = util.target_directory(source_feature['properties'])
    if target_directory is None:
        target_directory = util.target_directory_for_point(point)

    try:

        for layer in layers:

            logging.info('Layer: \'' + layer + '\'')

            print('Found dates: ', end='', flush=True)
            criterion_date = end_date
            while criterion_date is not None:
```

prints something like this

```
Found dates: 20170630130831 Collecting available features for location 8404222738792 and date range [2016-04-16..2017-06-30]...
20170630130831 Layer: '1_NATURAL_COL0R'
2017-06-22 2017-05-13 2017-04-23 2017-04-03 2017-03-14 2017-02-22 2017-01-23 2016-11-24 2016-10-05 2016-08-06 2016-07-17 2016-06-27 2016-06-07
```

i.e. print outputs interleaved with logger outputs.

How to synchronize? I wan't logs printed in the same moment as they called and doesn't interleave with print's.

**UPDATE**

Logging initialized with following

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S', level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that initiates your logger?

Comment: your logging framework should take care of this?

Comment: You could make a function that will handle both printing and logging? Or I misanderstood?

Comment: @Chris_Rands see my update please about logging init.

Comment: @Dims Does this work (after each log) `logging.Handler().flush()`?

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. By default `StreamHandler` log all data into `sys.stderr`. And `print` prints data to `sys.stdout`. So your program is syncronized, but your terminal doesnt. Try to manually create `StreamHandler` and pass `stream=sys.stdout` into constructor. After that your output should be passed to `stdout` and all will be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Logging functions are manly made to indicate that certain events have occurred.
Print function to display things for user.
If you want avoid interleaving with printf, you can simply put your logs into text file.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I want `stdout` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `stream` to `sys.stdout` in your `basicConfing()` call:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y%m%d%H%M%S', level=logging.INFO)
```

or print to `sys.stderr` stream:

```
print('Found dates: ', end='', flush=True, file=sys.stderr)
```